# i want to know why i get error but please in easy way as i am beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def test() : # do not change this line!
  
values = [4, 7, 8, 9, -5] # do not change this line!
  if values[4] < 0 : values.remove(values[4])
  tag = (values[0] + values[1])/2
  values.insert(1, tag)
  values[0] = 9 
  values[4]= 4
  print(values)
    return values# do not change this line!
# do not write any code below here  

test()  # do not change this line!
# do not remove this line!
```

return values# do not change this line!
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
)

Comment: the problem that I must use ( return values ) to pass

Comment: Your indentations are incorrect. I would suggest going through a basic python course.

Comment: The title should reflect the problem or error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Python is very strict with indentation. Your return statement is not properly indented and python treats it as separate block. Please remove indentation before return statement and also add indentation on the first line in the function.

Answer (score 0):

try using >>>

```
def test() : # do not change this line!
  
  values = [4, 7, 8, 9, -5] # do not change this line!
  if values[4] < 0 : values.remove(values[4])
  tag = (values[0] + values[1])/2
  values.insert(1, tag)
  values[0] = 9 
  values[4]= 4
  print(values)
  return values# do not change this line!
# do not write any code below here  

test()  # do not change this line!
# do not remove this line!
```

You need to indent the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made some syntactical structure mistake

```
def test():  # do not change this line!

    values = [4, 7, 8, 9, -5]  # do not change this line!
    if values[4] < 0:
        values.remove(values[4])
    tag = (values[0] + values[1])/2
    values.insert(1, tag)
    values[0] = 9
    values[4] = 4
    print(values)
    return values  # do not change this line!
    # do not write any code below here


test()
```

In python there is no curly braces to identify the code block, so if you not correctly indent then you'll miss the loop flow. Let me know if your issue is solved